# Is a closed $G_\delta$ set in a Hausdorff space always a zero set?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I have been trying to prove that if $A$ is a closed set which is also an intersection of countably many open sets then $A$ is the zero set for some continuous real-valued function however have thus far failed. Is this even true?

Answer (score 9):

It is not true.

John Thomas, [*A regular space, not completely regular*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2317272), Amer. Math. Monthly **76** (1969), 181-182, constructed a regular Hausdorff space $X$ with two points, $p$, and $q$, such that for each continuous $f:X\to\Bbb R$, $f(a)=f(b)$. Moreover, $X$ has countable local bases at $p$ and $q$. Thus, $\{p\}$ is a closed $G_\delta$-set in $X$ that cannot be a zero-set: any zero-set containing $p$ must also contain $q$.

A. Mysior, [*A regular space which is not completely regular*](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1981-081-04/S0002-9939-1981-0601748-4/), Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. **81** (1981), 652-653, is freely available and has a regular Hausdorff space with a point $p$ and a closed set $F$ such that for each continuous $f:X\to\Bbb R$ and $x\in F$, $f(x)=f(p)$. The point $p$ has a countable local base, so here again $\{p\}$ is a closed $G_\delta$ that cannot be a zero-set.

Comment: Why is it clear that $\{p\}$ is a $G_{\delta}$-set? For a topology which is sufficently rich (e.g. if it is metrizable), we can find a sequence of open sets $(U_n)$ with $x=\bigcap_n U_n$, and so $\{x\}$ is $G_{\delta}$. But how do we construct the sequence here? (I guess I'm missing something obvious...)

Answer (score 3):

Not even in completely regular Hausdorff spaces.  In general we have
$$
\text{compact $G_\delta$}\qquad\Longrightarrow\qquad
\text{zero-set}\qquad\Longrightarrow\qquad
\text{closed $G_\delta$}
$$
but none reversible.

Comment: A bit late too the party, but could you point me to a reference to the proof of compact $G_\delta \implies $ zero-set?

Comment: what can be example for completely regular space?

Comment: @John The implication compact $G_\delta \Rightarrow$ zero-set holds for a completely regular Hausdorff space, see e.g. [Fremlin, "Measure Theory", 4A2Fh(v)] for a proof. In a completely regular Hausdorff space you can separate compact sets from open sets by continuous functions.

Comment: @yada I think you meant, you can separate compact sets from closed sets by continuous function in a Tychonoff (which I prefer to call them) space.

Answer (score 1):

Brian's answer covers the question fully. For fun, here's another example:

Bing's [irrational slope space](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1953-0060806-9) is a countable and connected Hausdorff space.

Now observe:

1. If $f \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then $f(X)$ is a countable and connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$, hence it must be reduced to a point. Therefore all continuous functions $f \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ are constant, and the only zero sets are the empty set and the space itself.
2. Since $X$ is countable and $T_1$, every subset $F$ of $X$ is a $G_\delta$-set: $F = \bigcap_{x \in X \setminus F} X \setminus \{x\}$, in particular, there is an abundance of closed $G_\delta$ sets that are not zero sets.